# solution verification modular arithmetic

Tags: solution-verification, modular-arithmetic

I am looking for solution verification. I am trying to grasp the very very basic idea of modular arithmetic. I am sure there are lot of other ways to go about it assuming I did these problems correctly.

$3k \equiv 7 \pmod{13}$ since we are in $\mod(13)$ we only look at the values $k=0,...,12$

so $$3k -7 \equiv 0 \pmod{13}$$

$(k = 1) \space 3 - 7 =-4$

$(k = 2) \space 6 - 7 = -1$

$(k = 3) \space 9 - 7 = 2$

$(k = 4) \space 12 - 7 = 5$

$(k = 5) \space 15 - 7 = 8$

$(k = 6) \space 18 - 7 = 11$

$(k = 7) \space 21 - 7 = 14$

$(k = 8) \space 24 - 7 = 17$

$(k = 9) \space 27 - 7 = 20$

$(k = 10) \space 30 - 7 = 23$

$(k = 11) \space 33 - 7 = 26$

Now listing multiples of $13$:

13

26

39

we get $26$ when $k = 11$ so the answer is $11$

$4k \equiv 2 (\mod 7)$

$4k - 2 \equiv \space 0 (\mod 7)$

we look at the values from $0,1,2....6$

$(k = 1) 4 - 2 = 2$

$(k = 2) 8 - 2 =6$

$(k = 3) 12 - 2 = 10$

$(k = 4) 16 - 2 = 14$

$(k = 5) 20 - 2 =18$

$(k = 6) 24 - 2 = 22$

listing multiples of $7: 7, 14 , 21 , 28$

we get $14$ when when $k = 4$ so the solution to the congruence equation is $k = 4$

Comment: You are asked to solve for $k$ in $3k\equiv 7\pmod{13}$?  Then do so without brute force... that is the point of what you should be currently studying.  If this were talking about solving for $k$ in $3k\equiv 7\pmod{100^{100}}$ you would *not* be wanting to list out all googol of the different lines.

Comment: Find the multiplicative inverse of $3$ in your ring... then note that $k\equiv 3^{-1}\times 7\pmod{13}$ and you are done.  The only challenge remaining is to actually calculate $3^{-1}$ which you should have been taught several techniques how to find, the most common of which is to use the extended euclidean division algorithm.

Comment: so the method that I used did not even yield the correct value?

Comment: Oh, it very probably did, but I didn't bother checking.  Even if it were correct, you should familiarize yourself with the far superior approaches.

Comment: which is the best method to go about?

Comment: without exponents being involved. say exponents are involved then what method?

Comment: Again, find $3^{-1}$, either through euclidean division algorithm or by inspection, or however you like.  You will find that $3^{-1} \equiv 9\pmod{13}$ (*spotted by inspection since $3\cdot 9 = 27 =2\cdot 13 + 1 \equiv 1\pmod{13}$ but can be found through routine processes and calculations if you wish*) and so $k\equiv 3^{-1}\cdot 7 \equiv 9\cdot 7 \equiv 63\pmod{13}$ which you can simplify further.

Comment: your answers are correct, though there are more efficient methods to obtain them

Comment: okay my professor has office hours today so I will surely look for better methods

Comment: See the linked dupes (and their links) for many efficient methods to solve such congruences.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Find a Bézout's relation $3u+13 v=1$ to determine the inverse $u$ of $3$ modulo $13$, so that you  have 
$$3k\equiv 7\mod 13\iff k\equiv u\cdot 7\mod 13. $$

Answer (score 0):

For small numbers, a practical method is as follows.

> $4k\equiv 2\mod 7$

Run through the addition of $2$ to successive multiples of $7$.
$$2,9,16,...$$
until you get a multiple of $4$.

The solution is $k=4.$

> $3k\equiv 7\mod 13$

$7,20,33,...$

The solution is $k=11.$

Comment: Okay so I see that 16 is a multiple of 4 but how does that tell me that my answer is 4?

Comment: You want $4k$ to be $16$.

Answer (score 0):

$$3k=13n+7\iff 3(k-2n)=7(n+1)$$

So you can take $n+1=3$ and $k-2n=7$, or $k=11$.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea behind modular arithmetic is to express quantities in the form of linear polynomials with integer slopes ( okay one way to state the basic idea). So we have:

$y\equiv b\pmod m\iff y=mx+b$

This gives us the power to reduce higher numbers (like 78 digits +) down to easily workable sizes. It also allows reducing input size in higher degree polynomials, find solutions, including integer roots, as they need to be roots modulo every integer.  Even assessing what solutions will look like to diophantine equations.

Your solutions are correct, but it's the tedious way to go.  Once k is greater than 7 you could start using mod 7 to skip some.

Another way is to use the definition to get $3k=13x+7=(3\cdot 4+1)x+(3\cdot 2+1)$ which means $z\equiv 2\pmod 3$  by distributivity and additive inverse. Then we check $13\cdot 2+7=33=3\cdot 11$ making $k=11$ a solution.

There are obviously other methods, like modular multiplicative inverse ( to do the equivalent of division), etc. but they're more useful for when you can't calculate a minimum $x$ value quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Your reasoning is correct but you are making it way too hard.

Its easier to and or subtract thirteen to get into range immediately.

$(k=1) 3-7=-4\implies -4+13=9$.

$(k=2) 6-7=-1\implies -1 + 13=12$.

$(k=3) 9-7 = 2$

$(k=4) 12-7=5$

$(k=5) 15-7=8$.

$(k=6) 18-7=11$

$(k=7) 21-7=14\implies 14-13=1$.

$(k=8) 24-7=17\implies 17-13=4$

$(k=9) 27-7=20\implies 20-13=7$.

$(k=10) 30-7=23\implies 23-13=10$

$(k=11) 33-7=26 \implies 26-13=13\implies 13-13 = 0$ *!STOP!*

.... It's even easier to just realize that each step is $3$ more than the last and *circle* AS you go around.

To get $3k \equiv 7\pmod {13}$ just add $3$ until you reach $7$....

$3, 6,9,12,15\equiv 2,5,8,11,14\equiv 1, 4, \color{blue}7$.

And that is ...one, two, three, .... , $11$ terms in.

Of course we are making it way too hard on ourselves.

$3$ and $13$ are relatively prime so one of $7, 7+13,$ or $7+26$ will be divisible by $3$.  $7$ isn't, and $7+13=20$ isn't but $7+26 = 33 = 3*11$ is.

So $3*11 \equiv 7 \pmod {13}$ is a solution.

....

Of course that could be hard if we were aske to solve $17k \equiv 56\pmod {89}$.

It be too much work to list $56, 56+89, 56+2*89,....., 56+16*89$ and seeing which one is divisible by $17$ (although that will work in theory)

Instead we can figure that $89 = 5*17+4$ so $1*89 - 5*17 = 4$..

And $17 = 4*4 + 1$ so $1 = 1*17 - 4*4$ so

$1 = 1*17 - 4*(1*89 - 5*17) = 1*17 +20*17 -4*89 = 21*17 -4*89$

so $17*21 = 1 + 4*89$ so

$17*21 \equiv 1 \pmod{89}$

sp $17*(21\times 56) \equiv 56\pmod{89}$

Now $21*56= 84*14 =(89-5)*14 = -70 + 14*89 =19 + 15*89$

so $17*(21\times 56) = 17*(19 + 15*89) = 17*19 + 17*15*89\equiv 56\pmod{89}$ and the solution is $17*19\equiv 56 \pmod {89}$.